# How do I update a parent repository's history to reflect changes made to a submodule's history done using 'git branch-filter'?

Tags: git

I have two Git repositories which I'll call **A** and **B**. Repo **B** happens to be a submodule of Repo **A**.

Repo **B** is chock full of binary files that I'd like to wipe from history. I can easily run a branch-filter command to erase those files from repo **B**'s history. That's not my problem.

My problem is that, after running branch-filter on repo **B**, thousands of commits in repo **A** will now point to (now-invalid) commits in repo **B**.

So my question is: How do I modify the history of repo **A** so that each commit of repo **A** points to the correct commit of repo **B**?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When filtering the submodule repository, you need to remember how each commit ID changed (in a map). Then you need to filter the parent repository as well, and for each change to the submodule, instead of using the old commit ID, get the equivalent new ID from the map and use it. I'm not sure how to do all this in practice, since I've never done it, but here are a few ideas:

The [man page](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-filter-branch.html#_filters) says that there's a `map` function available that will print which new ID corresponds to an old ID, so you could use that one to create the permanent map file.

To correct the submodule IDs, you have to use `--index-filter` with a rather complex script that uses `git ls-files -s`, a script that transforms this stage information to reference the new commit IDs (I use `sed` when faced with similar tasks), and `git update-index --index-info` that uses the new stage information for the rewritten commit.

Answer (score 0):

I am not a git expert.

It seems to me that since you changed history you need to remove the submodule and then re-add it.

#### Remove the entries in the .gitmodules file:

> ```
> [submodule "B"]
> path = B
> url = git@server:B
> ```

#### Remove the submodule's entry in the .git/config file

> ```
> [submodule "b"]
> url = git@server:B
> ```

#### Remove the path created for the submodule

> git rm --cached B

Now add the submodule back.

I am not sure how you ever fix the history in another repo if it's origin had a history rewrite without recloning.